# how to create a win32 application with Windows menus using c++ and using the visual studio 2017 menu editor

Tags: c++, menu

After creating a win32 project using visual Studio 2017 community I have added to the menus pop downs that are already there. After I added below 'File' a popup item 'Mypop', I opened the properties of the new option and copied the ID; 'ID_FILE_MYPOP' into my WndProc WM_COMMAND loop.

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)

...
case ID_FILE_MYPOP:
break;

It appears with error message "identifier ID_FILE_MYPOP is undefined".

I can only correct this by opening the resource.h file, it responds "this file is already open in another device do you want to close it?". If I reply yes, then I can see the contents of resource.h file and it includes ID_FILE_MYPOP. Then if I close the resource.h file the error message in WndProc disappears and the menu addition works correctly.

MY QUESTION IS:

Do I have to open and close the resource.h header file every time I add a menu item to resource.rc file?

What application might have the resource.h file open?

If anyone could help me I would really appreciate it.

ps I can also remove the error statement if I open and shut the project solution.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM 
lParam)
{
    switch (message)
{
    case WM_COMMAND:
    {
        int wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
        // Parse the menu selections:
        switch (wmId)
        {
        case  ID_FILE_MYPOP:
            break;
        case IDM_ABOUT:
            DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, About);
            break;
        case ID_NEWEDITIDAPPROACH:
            break;
        case IDM_NEW7:
            break; 
        case IDM_EXIT:
            DestroyWindow(hWnd); 
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        }
    }
    break;
```

...}

Answer (score 0):

Double click the resource file in the solution explorer - the resource editor should open (and this is the app opening the resource.h):

[image: Resource file in the solution explorer]

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have always double clicked on, in my case, Win32test.rc and I can create a popup menu and obtain an ID. But when I close Win32test.rc the ID gives the error code  "this file is already open in another device do you want to close it?" and the problem remains as described above. ie Do I have to open and close the resource.h header file every time I add a menu item to resource.rc file?

Comment: Both the rc file and the related header can be either opened in the text editor OR in the resource editor. Opening the files in the text editor causes usually that questions from VS. I know that this is confusing and not properly solved (e.g. a "show definition" opens often the header file). 
So usually both files should be closed -- then the resource editing should work.

Comment: Its surprising that something so basic as adding a resource is so clumsy. It is reassuring to hear that you have found the same clumsiness, thankyou for your comments.